# Why did the variable values change after entering the string?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

When a new line is entered for processing via cin.getline, the values of variables not related to this line at all change. Why might this be happening?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            std::cin.getline(command, maxLen);
        }
--->    std::cin.getline(command, maxLen);
        processCommand(command);
    }
```

```
Heap.MinHeap.elem[1]->value = 7 -----changes into----> Heap.MinHeap.elem[1]->value = 2067606717
```

UPD.

A char string is entered, for example "extract_min", which should output the minimum from the heap. But it has not yet reached the place where it should be performed. At that time, the values of the variables in the heap change. And this does not depend on the size of the string or the size of the heap (in my case, I store pointers to elements), I tried to change, but still the same problem.

Comment: Which values do you refer to?

Comment: What you describe happens when you have a **buffer overflow**. How is `command` being allocated, and what is `maxLen` set to?

Comment: `const int maxLen = 1000; char command[maxLen];`
The values change in the fields of the data structures.

Comment: Maybe the bug is in `processCommand()`

Comment: No, this happens exactly at the moment of reading the line, without going into the function.

Comment: Comment out `processCommand()` and see if the problem still happens. Undefined Behavior sometimes will cause very unexpected results.